# Why does my wired button always read HIGH?

Tags: button, led, debugging, potentiometer

I have made a simple Arduino program that uses a potentiometer to dim a LED.

This program also makes a second LED blink.

Finally, I have added a button that controls a third LED; this part of my program does not work: the 3rd LED is always lit as the button always reads HIGH.

Here is the code:

```
//sensePin is wired up to the FSR
int sensePin = 2;

//this is wired up to an LED
int ledPin = 9;

//Wired up to a button
int inputPin = 1;

int val = 0;

//I was broed so added the default Blink
int ledPinX = 13;

//Wired up to a second LED
int ledPinY = 7;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(inputPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(ledPinX, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPinY, OUTPUT);
  val = digitalRead(inputPin);
}

void loop() {
  if (val == HIGH){
    //This should ask "If your button is pressed, then do the code below
    digitalWrite(ledPinY, HIGH);
    //but for some reason the light is always on. I've tried it with more than one button
  }
  else if(val == LOW){
    digitalWrite(ledPinY, LOW);
  }
  int value;

  /*
 The rest of this stuff works. Well, it did before adding in the button. Now the FSR acts as a digital input. Please help.
   */
  value = analogRead(sensePin) / 4;
  analogWrite(ledPin, value);
  digitalWrite(ledPinX, HIGH);
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(ledPinX, LOW);
  delay(500);
}
```

What did I do wrong in this code?

EDIT:: diagram and pic at: instagram.com/p/m3AmHWmp4e

Comment: Could you the part of your circuit showing how the button is wired to the Arduino?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You read the button once, in `setup()`. The function is not called every time the variable's value is read, only when the line is executed and the variable assigned to. Move the `digitalRead()` call and assignment into `loop()`, before you check the variable's value.

Comment: ok that helps a bit but when I run it the ledPinY stays on the entire time instead of responding to the button

Comment: http://pastebin.com/tBiHX7Zw

Ok the button still wont read input and I just revamped the code from scratch just to get the button working then I'll implement sensePin. It compiles fine but always digitalWrites HIGH to ledPinX

Comment: EDIT:: Taking a look at the button example i figured out whree I went wrong. I may just use that and integrate the FSR code

EDIT:: It doesnt work either

Comment: ummm.. even witht the button gone and input jumper cables pulled that output is screwed up

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with your code is that you read the button state **only once** at the beginning of your program in `setup()`, so it keeps the initial value forever.

You should modify `loop()` as follows:

```
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(ledPinY, digitalRead(inputPin));
  ...
}
```

You can also remove the `val` variable, it is totally useless here; then you must also simplify `setup()`:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(inputPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(ledPinX, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPinY, OUTPUT);
  // val = digitalRead(inputPin);
}
```

Comment: I added the diagram to the original quesiton

Answer (score 0):

Pin 1 is used for the serial output and can't be used if you enable serial using `serial.begin(9600)`.

Change button to pin 2.